# array not binding to select using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-promise

i am populating a collection called CommandGroup like this

```
        function getCommandGroups() {
        $scope.commandGroups = commandGroupResource.query();

        return $scope.commandGroups.$promise.then(function (response) {

            $scope.commandGroups = response;

        });

    }
```

my html looks like this.

```
                        <select ng-model="vm.Job.CommandGroup" name="ddlCommandGroup" bootstrap-dropdown>
                        <option value="">Select Something</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="cmdGroup in commandGroups" value="{{cmdGroup.Id}}">{{cmdGroup.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
```

for some reason drop down remains empty. The function getCommandGroups() calls back end and populates commandGroups with array of objects each of which has Id and Name.

Please help.

[image]

**UPDATE**

i figured out something is wrong with the directive bootstrap-dropdown which is required as it is Bootstrap-select

```
angular
.module('app').directive('bootstrapDropdown', ['$timeout',
    function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '?ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {                  
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.selectpicker();
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: could you confirm that `response` does have that value?

Comment: yes response is fine

Comment: i added an image of the response.

Comment: could you try to place `{{commandGroups}}` seems like you are facing scope related issue..you placed this div inside `ng-if` or `ng-repeat`

Comment: It's not clear to me, why (and what) you return from `getCommandGroups()` - only the first line is needed. you may delete the entire return statement.

Comment: commandGroupResource is using $resource internally to return thats why i am using promise.

Comment: can you provide a codepen for your code ?

Comment: everything works if i have a hard coded array of commandGroups . but since it is being returned by a promise its not working properly. ill try to create a codepen.

Comment: @Pnkaj  what do you mean by " place {{commandGroups}}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the third-party JavaScript (bootstrap-select) doesn't get informed about the change.
You probably have to call **selectpicker('refresh')** on the element after assigning the response to commandGroups.

**Update**:
It's also required to use $scope.$apply() before calling selectpicker('refresh'):

```
function getCommandGroups() {
    $scope.commandGroups = commandGroupResource.query();

    return $scope.commandGroups.$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.commandGroups = response;
        $scope.$apply();
        $('.mySelect').selectpicker('refresh'); 
    });
}
```

See comment below for a fork of Taylor Buchanan's Plunk to see this in action.

**Update 2**: Use timeout instead to prevent a "digest already in progress" error:

```
function getCommandGroups() {
   $scope.commandGroups = commandGroupResource.query();

   return $scope.commandGroups.$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.commandGroups = response;
        $timeout(
           function(){
               $('.mySelect').selectpicker('refresh'); 
           }
        );
   });
}
```

Comment: i added      class="mySelect"    in html and 

                $scope.commandGroups = response;
                $('.mySelect').selectpicker('refresh');

still no luck.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the line element.selectpicker in the bootstrapDropdown directive, just for troubleshooting? You should see the regular select-box, does that one get updated after you assigned the new value to commandGroups? If not, does it help adding a $scope.$apply() after that?

Comment: I've just played with Taylor Buchanan's Plunk and forked it to include the bootstrap-JavaScripts and CSS:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MFhElUgAnCNY9XY0SdRV?p=preview
Adding $scope.$apply() before updating the bootstrap-dropdown using selectpicker('refresh') works in this Plunk. I think this might have been the issue.

Comment: whats in the plunkr i followed it it works, means idea of apply before selectpicker works but i also get   digest i progress error.

Comment: I see. I guess it's a "digest already in progress" error? In that case, instead of using scope apply, use a timeout.

Comment: Lil hint where to use time out? In directive ?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to provide the code in the comment but hitting return posted the comment instead of making a line break. I've added the code to the answer instead now.
Using $timeout without a delay time will execute the code inside when the digest cycle is over, thereby making sure that everything is up to date before refreshing your bootstrap selector.

Comment: awsomee its working would like to mark it as an answer. but please one advice can this be done some how in directive, because these kind of control initiation is done in directive  ? i guess no because this refresh needs to happen after response i assigned to commandGroups . make sense but i guess i have to accept is as a problem with the control .  what u say

Comment: It can be done in the directive if you add a watcher using $watch. You'd have to write your directive in such a way that you can pass it the name of the model to watch.

Comment: something like scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue, oldValue) {
         
           
           });

Comment: I currently don't have the time to go deeper into this but I think you're on the right track. Don't watch the select-element's model though because that's the model for the selected value, not for the array of possible values.

Comment: iv setup a question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187385/unable-to-pass-parameter-to-angular-directive
 i guess i am almost there as you suggested. Will appreciate if you could have a look.

Answer (score 1):

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EKpaIfZIBOth3Ry0tEUg?p=preview) contains the exact code you have provided, with the exception of the `bootstrap-dropdown` directive and your actual web service. The code functions as expected. This indicates there is a problem elsewhere in code you did not provide.

Possible issues:

1. <s>The `bootstrap-dropdown` directive is doing something funny.</s>

   a. **UPDATE**: The directive works "fine" in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dmTc2utnDleZRdIkdHeS?p=preview). Not sure what it's supposed to be doing, but it doesn't cause the behavior you describe.
2. You are missing an `ng-controller` in your markup.
3. Something else we can't see is clearing out $scope.commandGroups.

Comment: i have updated my question. something is wrong with the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Reassigning $scope.commandGroups might be interfering with promise resolution/ scope digest cycle. Try changing the function to the following:

```
function getCommandGroups() {
    commandGroupResource.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
        $scope.commandGroups = response;
    });
}
```